# Multiple javascript live updating input fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to have more than one input which can output what the user has put inside the input box on one page and for it to update live. I can currently only get one input to work live.

HTML Code

```
<input type=text></input><!-- inputs live text -->
<p id="headingone"></p><!-- outputs live text -->
```

Javascript Code

```
function reverse(s) {
  return s.split('').reverse().join('')
}

function set(el, text) {
  while (el.firstChild) el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
}

function setupUpdater() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
    , orig = document.getElementById('headingone')
    , oldText = input.value
    , timeout = null;

  function handleChange() {
    var newText = input.value;
    if (newText == oldText) return;
    else oldText = newText;
    set(orig, newText);
  }

  function eventHandler() {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(handleChange, 50);
  }
  input.onkeydown = input.onkeyup = input.onclick = eventHandler;
}

setupUpdater();
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].focus();
```

Comment: Your markup only shows one input, so I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. The markup with your code looks fine as is.

Comment: you can probably only get one input to work, because in your `setupUpdater` method you are assigning `input` the value of the very first input element (`document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]) found in the DOM.